# Temporary repair for broken clutch pedal sensor

Tags: ford, clutch, fiesta

I have 2003 Ford Fiesta. My clutch master cylinder push rod came off of the pedal today. I put a cable tie on, it should hold it for a bit. But I also noticed a **sensor for the clutch pedal** that has fallen off (I think it was hit off by the clutch pedal when it flew up, following losing contact with the master cylinder).

As I can not fix properly or replace it today, **I am wondering what state to put the sensor in so that the engine manager will work in a sane way.** Do I disconnect the electrics, let it think I am pressing the clutch (by leaving it alone), depress it with a cable tie, so it thinks the clutch is up, or do I need it working properly?

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's some kind of new clutch pedal sensor I'm not aware of, I'm pretty sure they exist only to keep you from starting the engine with the clutch engaged. I always jumper the cable on them so I **can** start the engine with the clutch engaged, which is great in an emergency if the engine won't ignite (it allows you to move the car around a parking lot, off the street, etc. using the starter motor).

Comment: It's also a great way to "push start" your car if no-one's around to help you.

Comment: @JuannStrauss I am imagining you chasing your car down the road.

Comment: LOL. No, I sit in the driver's seat. You simply put your car in 1st or 2nd gear and turn the key. No need to push if you have a good battery and a working starter motor.

Comment: I think "push start" usually refers to what you do when the battery is dead. :-)

Comment: Another possible purpose of the sensor: to disengage the cruise control when the clutch is put in.  My car has such a feature, though I am not sure if it is controlled by the clutch pedal sensor or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Since the vehicle won't start the switch needs to be in the opposite state of it's current position. I would either jump the contacts of the connector or wire tie/tape the switch in the closed position. However this must be used only long enough to properly fix the switch. This is a condition that could result in some serious damage or injury. Since you have experienced clutch issues already another pedal linkage failure could let the car lurch forward or reverse while starting.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how Ford does it, but on my Mitsubishi Eclipse, the clutch position switch is normally closed.  It goes open when the clutch is disengaged.  Simply unplugging the wiring from the switch will perform the bypass on my car.